# why putting 2 semicolon is not an error?

Tags: c++

I just find out that no matter how many semicolons (if more than 0) the compiler will compile without error

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int x;
   x = 5;;
   std::cout << x;;; 
}
```

will just works fine, so why?

Comment: The C++ syntax allows and empty statement. (Why - probably inherited from C)

Comment: This is for C but same reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876776/why-can-you-use-multiple-semicolons-in-c

Comment: @f.Alessio - Note this is not true in all instances: for example `if (condition) statement;; else statement` will fail.

Comment: Simply put: the language grammar allows it and it is even occasionally useful - especially when working with lots of macros. Also a boon if you get paid based on the number of lines of code you write ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not an error because the language standard says so. It's OK to have empty statements, they do nothing, and are harmless.

There are times when it's useful:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#define DEBUG_LOG(X) std::cout << X << std::endl;
#else
#define DEBUG_LOG(X)
#endif

int main()
{
  DEBUG_LOG(1);
}
```

When `DEBUG` is not defined this will expand to:

```
int main()
{
  ;
}
```

If you couldn't have empty statements that would not compile.

Comment: That's a nice trick with macro, but I would replace it with `do std::cout << X << std::endl; while (0)` anyway to avoid any potential warnings about extra semicolon.

Comment: Yes, that's how to write it in real programs (and not because of warnings, but because it can be used correctly after if/else), but I wanted to keep it simple to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon is a terminal, a token that terminates something. What exactly it terminates depends on the context. 
For example, a semicolon character is at the end of the following parts of the C++ grammar (not necessarily a complete list):

```
an expression-statement
a do/while iteration-statement
the various jump-statements
the simple-declaration
```

Note that in an expression-statement, the expression is optional. That's why a 'run' of semicolons, ;;;;, is valid in many (but not all) places where a single one is.

Answer (score 2):

A semicolon terminates a statement, consecutive semicolons represent no operation / empty statement.

No code will be generated for empty statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two consecutive semicolons, there is an empty statement between them (just another way of saying: there is no statement between them). So, why are empty statements allowed?

Sometimes you need to use some construct, where the language expects a statement, but you dont want to supply one. For example, a common way to write a infinite loop is like this

```
for (;;) {
    // do something
    // ...and break somewhere
}
```

If c++ didnt allow empty statements, we would have to put some dummy statements instead of naked `;;` just to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `;;;` in between you have empty statements. Remember C++ doesn't care about white space.